# Inserting and deleting edges in a Tree Dynamically

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

**Problem :** Given a rooted Tree `T` containing `N` nodes. Each node is numbered form `1` to `N`, node `1` being the root node. Also, each node contains some value. We have to do three kind of queries in the given tree.

**Query 1::** 
Given a node `nd`, you have to find the sum of the values of all the nodes of the subtree rooted at `nd` and print the answer.

**Query 2::** 
Given a node `nd`, you have to delete the subtree rooted at `nd`, completely (including node `nd`).

**Query 3::** 
Given a node `nd` and some integer `v`, you have to add a child to node `nd` having value equal to `v`.

Constraints : `N` will be of the order of 100000. And total number of queries wil also be of the order 100000. So, I can't to DFS traversal every time.

**My Idea:**  My solution is  **offline** . I will first find all the nodes that are added to the tree at-least once and make the corresponding tree. Then I will do pre-order traversal to the tree and convert it into an array where a subtree will always appear continuously. Then I can use segment tree data structure to solve the problem. My algorithm will be thus O(**QlogN)**, where Q is the total number of queries. However, I am looking for a **"online"** solution which is efficient. I mean, I have perform each query as soon as it is asked. I can not store all the queries first then perform them one by one.

Any help is appreciated a lot!
Thanks.

Comment: Surprisingly similar to ["Dynamic Trees and Queries"](http://www.codechef.com/MAY14/problems/ANUDTQ) problem from ongoing CodeChef contest. The only difference is number of queries. Contest's problem has four, but here there are only three...

Comment: Amusingly, the problem title is a hint about how to solve it.

Comment: Just keep an each node a parent pointer and the subtree sum.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I don't find any such hint, could you please elaborate a liitle so that I can get the hint ?

Comment: @chill but when the tree is not balanced how can we do it efficiently ? For example if the tree is just linear and edges are added one by one at the bottom ?

Comment: Maybe after the Code Chef contest is over.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat OK, but when it is going to end ? will it end today itself ?

Comment: It is to end in 4 days. And usually 1 or 2 days later you could read editorials with detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming tree is balanced, with two extra parameters in every node you can solve it in o(qlogn).

With every node maintain a sum whose value will be equal to the sum of values of nodes in the subtree rooted at that and maintain parent as well.

With the above two requirements, query one just reduces to returning sum plus the value at that node(o(1)). query two reduces to just subtracting sum plus the value of node from every parent of that node till you reach the root(o(logn)). query three just reduces to adding v to every parent of that node till you reach the root(o(logn)).